# Match on existentially hidden type index

Tags: idris, existential-type

I'd like to match on an 'existentially hidden' type index, in order to write an `Eq` instance:

```
module Test

import Data.Vect

data Meep : Type where
  Moop : {n:Nat} -> Vect n Int -> Meep

Eq Meep where
  (Moop {n1} v1) == (Moop {n2} v2) = False
```

Subsequently, I'd like to have a view into `decEq n1 n2` to delegate to `Eq (Vect n Int)` or to return `False`.

But the above doesn't seem to work:

```
Type checking .\.\Test.idr
.\.\Test.idr:9:9:
When checking left hand side of Prelude.Interfaces.Test.Meep implementation of Prelude.Interfaces.Eq, method ==:
n1 is not an implicit argument of Test.Moop
```

What is the actual Idris way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
Eq Meep where
  (Moop {n = n1} v1) == (Moop {n = n2} v2) with (decEq n1 n2)
    (Moop {n = n2} v1) == (Moop {n = n2} v2) | (Yes Refl) = v1 == v2
    (Moop {n = n1} v1) == (Moop {n = n2} v2) | (No contra) = False
```

Comment: Any quick pointer on how I can use a `with` pattern to match on `decEq n1 n2`?

Comment: Ah, just figured it out myself at this same moment. I missed parentheses around `decEq n1 n2` before. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: Were you using Idris interactively when going from the prior version to this one? If so, which transformations were you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Emacs. I started with `(Moop {n = n1} v1) == (Moop {n = n2} v2) = ?todo`, then pressed `C-c C-w` to get `(Moop {n = n1} v1) == (Moop {n = n2} v2) with (_)
    (Moop {n = n1} v1) == (Moop {n = n2} v2) | with_pat = ?Moop_rhs`, then changed the underscore (`_`) to `decEq n1 n2` and then did case analysis on `with_pat` using `C-c C-c` and, finally, case-analysed `prf` to get `Refl` after `Yes`.